# can php return a boolean? => return $aantal == 0;

Tags: php, syntax, variables, boolean, return

can php return a boolean like this:

```
return $aantal == 0;
```

like in java you can

```
public boolean test(int i)
{
return i==0;
}
```

or do you Have to use a if contruction?
because if i do this.

```
$foutLoos = checkFoutloos($aantal);

function checkFoutloos($aantal)
{
    return $aantal == 0;
}

echo "foutLoos = $foutLoos";
```

it echo's

```
foutLoos =
```

so not true or false

thanks
matthy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It returns a boolean, but the boolean is not converted to a string when you output it. Try this instead:

```
$foutLoos = checkFoutloos($aantal);

function checkFoutloos($aantal)
{
    return $aantal == 0;
}

echo "foutLoos = " . ( $foutLoos ? "true" : "false" );
```

Comment: just to add on, whenever you're doing comparison (using any comparison operators), the result will be boolean. If you're not sure, just use casting to make sure it's boolean. `return (bool)($aantal == 0);`

Answer (score 8):

Try it out!

```
function is_zero($n) {
    return $n == 0;
}

echo gettype(is_zero(0));
```

The output:

```
boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can return a boolean test in the return function. I like to put mine in parenthesis so I know what is being evaluated.

```
function Foo($Bar= 0) {
    return ($Bar == 0);
}

$Return = Foo(2);
$Type = var_export($Return, true);

echo "Return Type: ".$Type; // Return Type: boolean(true)
```

In fact, almost anything can be evaluated on the `return` line. Don't go crazy though, as it may make refactoring more difficult (if you want to allow plugins to manipulate the return, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

yes ideed i found out that when you echo a false you get nothing and true echo's 1 thats why i was confused ;)

Comment: PHP is loosely typed. It will convert you variable to the appropriate context. It's both good and bad.

Comment: I don't think "appropriate" is the word. You want to turn a boolean into a string, so it selects between "1" and ""?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  you can even through in the ternary operator.

```
function foo($bar == 0) {
    return ($bar) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do it like this i think, with type casting:

```
return (bool) $aantal;
```